# Framing root element in the XML Request/Response

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I generated the code from WSDL using top down approach.  My input/output XML structure from SOAP Webservice is generated as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.test.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:operationName>
           <RootElement> .......
               -----
           </RootElement>
     </web:operationName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.test.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:operationNameResponse>
           <RootElement> .......
               -----
           </RootElement>
     </web:operationNameResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is how I declared the SEI

```
@WebService
public interface classname
{
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "RootElement")
public abstract String operationName(@WebParam(name = "RootElement") String data)
}
```

want to avoid the `<web:operationName>` element coming in the Body above my Root element. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that output by setting the following properties on the [`javax.jws.SOAPBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/jws/soap/SOAPBinding.html) annotation

- `style`: `DOCUMENT`
- `use`: `LITERAL`
- `parameterStyle` : `BARE`. The default here is `WRAPPED` which is precisely what you *don't* want